# File upload and display image in angularjs

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

How to upload image in angularjs and store its path to sql server and display it in asp.net mvc application by using angularjs.

Comment: This is a very broad question which reads like you want others to do your work for yo. If you try it yourself, feel free to ask specific questions with code examples on any problems you encounter along the way. But I don't think anyone will answer this for you.

Comment: yesterday i posted my code for the same question but i m still in seek of answer for that question that's why i raised a question like this today whether u people will respond at least  to this or not??

Comment: Posting duplicate questions with no info won't help. We aren't obliged to help so make it easier for us by creating a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code you placed in the previous question was superfluous and didn't even attempt what you are asking for help with besides having a file input field. The advice of using angular-file-upload is good, if you tried this before why not show said code so we can debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been in this situation and how I handled it was used [this directive](https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs) to get the image in my controller easily and then send a request to an action in ASP.NET MVC. Save the file on disk and save the path in database. Like below for example:

```
public void UploadImage()
{
  HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["uploadedImage"];

  // write your code to save image
  string uploadedPath = Server.MapPath("~/") + file.FileName;
  file.SaveAs(uploadedPath);

  //save uploadedPath in database
}
```